# "didn't get news" VS "had no news"

Tags: phrase-choice, translation

What is the best translation for

> Bonjour Patrick, Malheureusement, "Je n'ai pas eu de nouvelle de Tom". Bonne journée.

Should I say

> "I didn't get news from Tom."

or I should say

> "I had no news from Tom."

Answer (score 1):

Usually we would use the present perfect here:

> I haven't had any news from Tom

or

> I haven't heard from Tom.

However, suppose that the writer regularly receives news from Tom, or has a particular expectation of receiving news from Tom at a particular point in time which has passed, or has been asked the question with reference to a specific point in time ("Did you hear from Tom yesterday?").  Then the writer might use the simple past:

> I didn't hear any news from Tom.
>
> I didn't hear from Tom.
>
> I didn't get any news from Tom.

But the present perfect would still be equally correct.

On the other hand, suppose that the writer wants to mention a specific date or time: the simple past then becomes mandatory:

> I didn't hear from Tom yesterday.
>
> I didn't hear from Tom at 4 pm.

The present perfect doesn't work in those sentences - although if the time expression was "today" then it would again become possible ("I haven't heard from Tom today").